# Unity run non-looped animation again when button is pressed

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I am currently creating some (non-looped) animations in Unity, that should start when a UI button is pressed. I have four buttons for four animations. Currently it works like that: I press button1 then animation1 is playing. If I then press button2 to play animation2, I can click again button1 to start animation1.

The thing is now: animation1 can only be played again, when another animation played before. So my question is: what do I need to change on the following code to let for example animation1 play every time button1 is pressed?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MultiAnimations : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator cubeAnimator;
    public bool anim1;
    public bool anim2;
    public bool anim3;
    public bool anim4;

// Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cubeAnimator.enabled = false;
        anim1 = false;
        anim2 = false;
        anim3 = false;
        anim4 = false;

    }

    public void anim1Clicked ()
    {
        cubeAnimator.enabled = true;
        anim1 = true;
        anim2 = false;
        anim3 = false;
        anim4 = false;

        if (anim1 == true)
        {
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim1", true);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim2", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim3", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim4", false);
        }
    }

    public void anim2Clicked ()
    {
        cubeAnimator.enabled = true;
        anim1 = false;
        anim2 = true;
        anim3 = false;
        anim4 = false;

        if (anim2 == true)
        {
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim1", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim2", true);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim3", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim4", false);
        }
    }

    public void anim3Clicked()
    {
        cubeAnimator.enabled = true;
        anim1 = false;
        anim2 = false;
        anim3 = true;
        anim4 = false;

        if (anim3 == true)
        {
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim1", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim2", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim3", true);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim4", false);
        }
    }

    public void anim4Clicked()
    {
        cubeAnimator.enabled = true;
        anim1 = false;
        anim2 = false;
        anim3 = false;
        anim4 = true;

        if (anim4 == true)
        {
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim1", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim2", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim3", false);
            cubeAnimator.SetBool("anim4", true);
        }
    }
}
```

The animations are connected with transitions and bools. I oriented myself on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_5FhXF9a3k

**SOLVED:** The code provided in the YouTube tutorial is pretty circuitously. You can save a lot lines of code to simple write it like that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MultiAnimations : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator cubeAnimator;

    // Play Animation 1 - Copy this for the other animations
    public void playAnimation1 ()
    {
        cubeAnimator.Play("animation1", -1, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put image of your animation states? I think someone should be able to help you if we can see the animator states

Comment: Unfortunately not. Stackoverflow only allows me to post images, when I have at least 10 reputations. Currently I have 9 :D

Comment: Oh no worries. You can post a link to the image also. No need to post as image only.

Comment: Here it is: https://i.imgur.com/NQlzvSi.jpg I conneted all four animation with transitions and created a bool for each animation that turns true/false depending on the transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's your update method? How are you calling these void methods?

Put an update method with conditions to check which button is clicked. So something like this:

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
       //Play animation. 
    }            
}
```

EDIT: Ok, when you press the button to play the first animation, and you press that button again, the animation is already true, so the animation already played. You need to set it to false after you're done playing the animation. Which is the reason why it plays again when you press other buttons.

EDIT: Try this style

```
public void anim1Clicked()
{
   animation.Play("anim1");
}
```

Comment: I call them with buttons (on the OnClick function of the button I've added an empty GameObject that has the script attached)

Comment: Ok so you're using the UI buttons.

Comment: Yes. I'll use the default UI buttons

Comment: Yeah I tried that. But it seems that some of the code isn't right (see my EDIT). There's a thread in the Unity forum, that says I need to call the Play function of the animator: https://answers.unity.com/questions/623878/how-to-restart-mecanim-state-animation-or-play-it.html 
Do I need to use this instead maybe?

Comment: Yea I was about to mention that Animator.Play is probably your best bet. Actually it would make your code a lot cleaner if you use the Play function. Because it would eliminate a lot of lines of code.

Comment: Yeah this did the trick. I used cubeAnimator.Play("anim1", -1, 0f); now it works. Thank you very much for your help!